# Devexpress gridview filter, paging and sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am new to DevExpress. In My project I am using web API.

So how can set **paging**, **sorting** and **filtering**?

Can I set `ObjectDataSource`? 
Currently, I set datatsouce manually. Add columns set, sortmode = custom, create event `OnCustomColumnSort`. But event is not fired.

Answer (score 0):

Of you want to use objectdatasource then its too much easy just create a stored procedure for select items or write query in objectdatasource and then assign this object datasource to the Devexpress grid then it will do all functionality for you

or follow the youtuv [Tips and Tricks for gridview in devexpress](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yUKCdtJOJb4)

Comment: get data from Web API. in this case what we do ?